# Cannot create proper Equatable function for usage with Array's .contains()

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tuples, swift2

I am trying to check whether an array of tuples contains a certain tuple using the native `contains()` method of `Array`. 
I have declared my two "equatable" functions as

```
public func ==(a: (clip1: Clip?, clip2: Clip?), b: (clip1: Clip?, clip2: Clip?)) -> Bool {

    let clipa1 = a.clip1
    let clipa2 = a.clip2
    let clipb1 = b.clip1
    let clipb2 = b.clip2

    if clipa1 != nil && clipa2 != nil && clipb1 != nil && clipb2 != nil {
        return (clipa1! == clipb1!) && (clipa2! == clipb2!)
    }
    else if clipa1 != nil && clipa2 == nil && clipb1 != nil && clipb2 == nil {
        return (clipa1! == clipb1!)
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

public func ==(a: Clip, b: Clip) -> Bool {
    return a.id == b.id
}
```

However when I try these in this manner

```
for clip in tmp {
                if !_filteredClips?.contains((clip1: clip.clip1, clip2: clip.clip2)) {
                    _filteredClips?.append(clip)
                }
            }
```

I am getting `Cannot convert value of type '(clip1: Optional<Clip>, clip2: Optional<Clip>)' to expected argument type '@noescape ((clip1: Clip?, clip2: Clip?)) throws -> Bool'`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of `contains` you are trying to use is only available for elements that adopt Equatable:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    /// Return `true` iff `element` is in `self`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func contains(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool
}
```

The tuple type (Clip?, Clip?) does not and you can't extend it. Since you've implemented ==, you can use the version of `contains` that takes a predicate like this.

```
for clip in tmp {
    if !_filteredClips!.contains({ $0 == clip }) {
        _filteredClips?.append(clip)
    }
}
```

See [How do I check if an array of tuples contains a particular one in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736244/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-of-tuples-contains-a-particular-one-in-swift) for other ideas.

Answer (score -1):

== can be used to test the equality of custom types such as structures, classes and tuples as the caller is doing here. The choice between == and === depends on whether your code needs to test for equality or identity, not on whether you are working with a class, struct, etc

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand where I should `isEqual`. Care to elaborate a little more please?

Comment: I am sorry, this is still unclear. Can you please be more specific on how to modify the code I pasted to avoid the compile time error I am getting?

Comment: This answer is misleading. == can be used to test the equality of custom types such as structures, classes and tuples as the caller is doing here. The choice between == and === depends on whether your code needs to test for equality or identity, not on whether you are working with a class, struct, etc.

Comment: gotcha.I se why it can be misleading. 
I've changed the answer